# How to enable mutual TLS on Google Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, mutual-authentication

According to the google documentation at https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-mtls, mutual TLS is an optional way of authenticating.

I have been trying to set this up with a nginx server as my Fulfilment Endpoint, however it does not appear that Dialogflow is actually sending a certificate with the request. If I make a request to the nginx server with curl using some letsencrypt certificates then it works as intended and the request is proxied to my API endpoint.

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name *.mysite.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
listen 443 default_server ssl;
server_name _;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/privkey.pem;
}
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name mysubdomain.mysite;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_client_certificate /home/user/cacert.pem;
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_verify_depth 10;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
location / {
  proxy_pass https://myapi/;
}
}
```

Is this function something that needs to be turned on somewhere for it to attempt an TLS connection? Has anyone got this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the mozilla bundle from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) does not play nicely. Using the google ones only has fixed this for me

```
curl https://pki.goog/gsr2/GTS1O1.crt | openssl x509 -inform der >> ca-crt.pem
curl https://pki.goog/gsr2/GSR2.crt | openssl x509 -inform der >> ca-crt.pem
```